# "get premium account" error with the Google Places API

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

I want to use google apis like [Google places api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview) and other apis, but it is telling me to get premium account.

I was testing this by making postman request. The error it returns is

> your account is not premium.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a legal / business question.

Comment: If the information you need cannot be found by reading the relevant Google documentation and FAQs, you should contact Google directly for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Google APIs are free to use and do not require any building.  Several of the Google Maps apis do require that you set up a billing account and you will be charged if you go over the testing quota allotment that they give you.

The easiest way to find out about pricing for an api is to check the documentation [Places api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview) if it does cost something to use it there will be a section called usage and billing.

[image]

What it probably means by that error message is that you need to enable a billing account, before you attempt to access the api.

> ## Pay-As-You-Go pricing
>
> The Places API uses a pay-as-you-go pricing model.
>
> - How usage and billing work under the pay-as-you-go model
> - The Google Maps Platform APIs are billed by SKU.
> - Usage is tracked for each Product SKU, and an API may have more than one Product SKU.
> - Cost is calculated by: SKU Usage x Price per each use.
> - For each billing account, for qualifying Google Maps Platform SKUs, a $200 USD Google Maps Platform credit is available each month, and automatically applied to the qualifying SKUs.